# How could I build this Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch with Spring Data and I have this configuration:

```
public class Address {

    //...

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = {
                    @InnerField(suffix = "raw", type = FieldType.Keyword)
            }
    )
    private String locality;

    //...

}
```

User can filter addresses by locality, so I'm trying to find the proper Elasticsearch query.

Say there are 2 documents:

```
{ /* ... */, locality: "Granada" }
{ /* ... */, locality: "Las Palmas de Gran Canaria" }
```

Given user input `granada` or `Granada`, I want to just the first document to be returned. However, using this query, both of them are returned.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "address.locality": "granada"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried with:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "address.locality.raw": "granada"
        }
    }
}
```

But, in that case, query is case sensitive and only returns first document when input is `Granada`, but not `granada`.

How could I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: Can you attach mappings for index Address? (GET /address/_mapping), it's weird as your first query should (with 'text' type) be tokenized to ['las', 'palmas', 'de', 'gran', 'canaria'].

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you get both documents with your query, nothing is returned when I try this, because *address* is not a property of your Document class.

The query should be

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "locality": "granada"
        }
    }
}
```

Then it returns just the one document.

The mapping that is produced using Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.0.RC2 when using this class:

```
@Document(indexName = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id private Long id;

    @MultiField(mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "raw", type = FieldType.Keyword) }) private String locality;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocality() {
        return locality;
    }

    public void setLocality(String locality) {
        this.locality = locality;
    }
}
```

is:

```
{
    "address": {
        "mappings": {
            "address": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "locality": {
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice is that **using match() queries** - Elasticsearch [analyzes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) (pre-processes) it queries ([tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) is performed: chops of spaces, removes punctuation and more...), **in the same way as it has been indexed**.

So if your "address.locality" string-field is indexed as 'text', it will use the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for both search (using match() query) and indexing.

**Term queries are not being analyzed** before search is executed, and thus different results might appear.

So in your example, our analysis process will look like:

> 1. locality: 'Granada' >> ['granada'], locality.raw: 'Granada' >> ['Granada']
> 2. locality: 'Las Palmas de Gran Canaria' >> ['las', 'palmas', 'de', 'gran', 'canaria'] locality.raw: 'Las Palmas de Gran Canaria' >> ['Las
>      Palmas de Gran Canaria']

**as for the second case**, "address.locality.raw" is indexed as 'keyword' which uses the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), this analyzer indexes the entire token (does not chop off anything).

**Possible solution**:

for first part: it should actually return only one document. if you set your property as P.J mentioned above.

for second part: index the innerfield type as `type = FieldType.Text`, which will break

> 'Granada' to 'granada'

thus term() queries of 'granada' will match - but any other term() query would not.
any match() queries of

> 'Granada', 'GRANADA', 'granada', etc...

will match as well (as it will be analyzed to 'granada' using the standard analyzer). This must be checked with your future use cases, maybe keyword indexing is relevant in your other use cases, and just change the query itself.